# How does AMP support author written JavaScript code?

Tags: amp-html

I'm confused how AMP supports author written javascript. I learned from the doc that AMP disable author written javascript, but why does it work when I directly insert javascript code in  tag? simple as the code below works fine on AMP page. Other code like I'm inserting a snippet of javascript code in  tag to load a service works fine too. Thanks.

```
​<script>
   alert("hi");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you are only permitted to use the JavaScript library that AMP provides – since you’re not in control, **you may experience lazy loading**. This might be the only downside to AMP. **Therefore, you can't use custom JS**. It has this [open proposed design](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/13471) for this issue. You can also probably check [AMP HTML Specification](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/spec/amphtml?referrer=ampproject.org) for more details about the supported tags.

Comment: Thanks for your answer jess. Am I understanding it right that as long as the js code asnyc, it won't cause any problem? Is "the JavaScript library that AMP provides" the AMP custom elements AMP provide [here](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/)? Thanks!

Comment: I mean, how do I know which scripts AMP support and which not? Or should I just not use script? Thanks!

Comment: Kindly check the documentation I have shared. You could see Required markup list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.